# Having trouble with adding a Swift package to MacOS 12.X+

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am writing my first MacOS App from the helloworld starter app.  I want to eventually write swift code that calls a thrift server running on the same machine.. but this libraries instructions simply state to modify a file I don't seem to have.

Are these instructions only applicable to iOS ?

```
### Installing

#### Swift Package Manager
Add the following to your Package.swift file


.package(name: "TwitterApacheThrift", url: "https://github.com/twitter/ios-twitter-apache-thrift", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.0.0"))


#### Carthage
Add the following to your Cartfile


github "twitter/ios-twitter-apache-thrift"
```

Source : https://github.com/twitter/ios-twitter-apache-thrift

MY Screenshot of my files

[image]

I tried the add package dialog with the URL but got an error

[image]

Comment: for now I've cloned the repo and "added it locally" but want to hear if there's a more proper way without manually recloning.. thanks

Comment: The package you want to add to your application supports macOS starting from version 10.15.4, you didn’t mention what macOS version targets your application.

Comment: I am targeting 12.x and above

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding correct URL. It needs to be "https://github.com/twitter/ios-twitter-apache-thrift.git" instead of "https://github.com/twitter/ios-twitter-apache-thrift" .  Means you need to add **.git** suffix. Also the instruction for installing that you posted
is meant for integrating thrift Package into another package as package dependency. If you just need to integrate the thrift package into your project, use the correct URL that I provided with standard way of adding package, as you tried before.

Comment: I amended the URL but the Xcode error is the same

Comment: When you type the URL into "search or enter package url", it cannot be found?

Comment: that pop up in the screencap is the same .. as if the git repo is not well formed.. but when I clone it locally and add it via /some/path/to/repo .. it works.. I guess I can live with that for now

Comment: Just today I faced kind of similar issue. It helped to delete all Derived Data , because SPM packages are also cached there.